# How would I make the background dim + unclickable and my image enlarged and centered when I click an image using JS/jQuery/any plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently fooling around with the Flickr API and am trying to make it so that I can search any image terms and a bunch of Flickr images would appear. However, I also want it so that when I click on the image, it sort of pops out while the background and everything else gets dark and you can't click it. Would I also need an "X" to close the picture after it's clicked so the user can continue surfing my site?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a Modal window. There are plenty of tutorials around to help you with that.

Comment: Try searching for "lightbox".

Comment: Gonna comment this here, so that you can see. This is a very rudimentary lightbox, but if you use it as a jumping off point, maybe you can form a more detailed question. Hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/GbtVT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) is your new friend, treat him well.

---

Some guides on how to use the Flickr API with FancyBox:

http://www.gregjopa.com/2010/12/flickr-feed-with-fancybox/

http://verivore.com/posts/6-flickr-photosets-and-fancybox-jquery

http://carst.me/2011/08/search-for-photos-using-jquery-flickr-api-and-fancybox-part-2/

<sub>(Top few results for searching `Fancybox + Flickr` on Google).</sub>

Comment: thanks for giving an actual answer instead of giving a sarcastic answer like the other guys. worked out perfectly.

Comment: wow FancyBox looks a lot nicer than lightbox - will give it a try on my next project! thanks

Answer (score 1):

place content in absolute or fixed positioned div and use another translucent div for background

Comment: yes u would also need to include in the content a button to hide both divs